# External HDD to internal HDD emulation in HDD Regenerator

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I was trying repair an old Hitachi hard drive of mine with HDD Regenerator and plugged it in with a SATA to USB cable (shown in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbOKf.jpg)).
But when I use HDD Regenerator and used the prescan option it proceeded up to 102MB, then it stopped with this error (shown in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QRqz.jpg)).

[image]

I'm running this in VMware Workstation because apparently HDD Regenerator causes problems for the hosts and the BIOS from the VM does not support changing form SATA to IDE.

My questions are:

1. Is there any software that enables changing SATA to IDE live in the OS?
2. Is there a way to emulate a external hard drive as an internal hard drive?

Comment: If you have access to another computer, @Z3R0_XP, try connecting this old HDD there as well and see if you will manage to get it repaired. If it's in an ext.enclosure, try taking it out as long as it's not covered by the warranty and plug it internally via SATA there. What exactly was the damage that you encountered with this drive? If the problem is physical/hardware-related, then you might be better off sending to a professional data recovery company for assistance with any important files from it.Either way, it won't be safe to store your data. What are the stats from the HDD's S.M.A.R.T.?

Comment: It is connected to another computer (and a virtual machine) image:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbOKf.jpg) and there is no need for data recovery because there is no data

Comment: @SuperSoph_WD here is the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNmDG.png
and it keeps on giving me this error when i get to 102mb:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QRqz.jpg [1] Is there any software that enables changing SATA to ide live in the OS [2] Is there a way to emulate a external hardrive as a internal hardrive

Comment: It looks like the HDD has quite the number of bad sectors! :( Unfortunately, Im not sure how successful your data retrieving attempts will be. Moreover, you need another HDD where you could transfer the data to. I'd also suggest you try connecting it internally, instead of using a SATA-to-USB cable when recovering files. I'd also suggest you consider using sector-by-sector data recovery instead. Still, if the files are very important to you, I'd definitely advise you again to turn to a professional data recovery company for assistance! Good luck!

Comment: There is no data on the dive the only important thing is the drive i need to repair it

Comment: Unfortunately, @Z3R0_XP, bad sectors cannot be fixed. If an HDD has started degrading due to reallocated sectors (bad), it means that its health  and SMART status will only get worse with time. You are lucky because you don't have to do any data recovery attempts, since there's nothing important. However, I'd still consider replacing the HDD altogether with a new one, if it's no longer covered by its manufacturer limited warranty. Good luck! Hope this was helpful.

Comment: is there any tools to fix the bad sectors besides Hddr or is it unfixable

Comment: With that many bad sectors, @Z3R0_XP, I'd definitely stop trying. You would be better off buying a new hard drive. It's hard to say if this is solely a logical issue or you might also be facing physical/hardware damage on the drive. There are two types of bad sectors — one resulting from physical damage that CAN'T be repaired, and one resulting from software errors that can be fixed. Either way, I'd definitely not trust any data with this drive, even if you do manage to get them repaired somehow. A brand new HDD would definitely save you a lot of headaches. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your harddisk has a real high amount of reallocated sectors (attributes 5 and 196).

Modern harddisks have a number of "spare" sectors they can use if a sector goes bad. They do that by reallocating the sector, which means they update an internal map that leaves the bad sector where it is, and uses one of the spare sectors instead.

The fact that this happened so often for your drive means that something is seriously wrong with your drive. You cannot "repair" it. If you keep using it, it will just continue to give you errors, and you'll loose data.

Throw it away and buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to benefit from the full power of Hdd regenerator you will have to run it at boot time and repair like that. So connect your HDD directly to a computer and make a bootable device with HDDR.

Running a repair via USB is NOT recommended at all.

Comment: But the problem is it can't boot from the bootable media  it keeps on giving me an error that the ram disk can't be loaded

Comment: Try a different media or get Hiren's Bootable CD and run HDDR from there.

Comment: Hiren's bootable Cd removed HDDR

Comment: There are plenty of the old versions that have it.

Comment: yeah i also tried hirens' boot cd verion 9.08 which had HDDR it didn't boot and gave me the ramdisk error

Comment: Well then try Ultimate Boot CD - should work in 1st try; or if you want to edit the disk content you can modify config.sys to use highmem.sys and resolve that, but that takes some ancient now-forbidden-and-forgotten MS-DOS knowledge. Hirens also got a fix tool: http://winbytes.org/help/hirens-boot/hirens-boot-cd-ramdisk-error.html

Comment: 1 It did the same thing in UBCD and how does Reimage fix the Ram disk error?

P.S If you didn't check out the link for the repair tool look at #2 (if you did then ignore this)

2 Reimage is a tool using cloud based fixing which fixes windows virus damage 
I have Bad sectors on a drive and there is no operating system installed It couldn't even install any operating system

Comment: Strange, that used to contain a fix tool for the boot image HMA, not a windows repair tool.